# Tips on sounding less nasal

Tags: voice

Kind of strange question, but I am wondering if there are any tips on changing the way your voice sounds. I am not looking for any dramatical improvements, but I am wondering if there are any small tips/techniques you can use to improve your voice.

In particular I am looking for techniques you can use to make your voice sound less nasal.

Answer (score 3):

Hmm... it all comes down to Practice.

When I took acting lessons we had some pronounciation training which involved speaking some training phrases with a cork or pencil between your teeth.

The phrases where like "Conrad continues counting computer components". We had one for every letter of the alphabet.

For getting rid of a nasal sound, I could imagine it would be helpful to try emulating a deep voice, and speak a little louder than usual. You will have to be beyond embarassment, for the camera work.

Maybe someone with experience in singing could give some helpful advice too.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Embarrassment is no factor for me as I do only voice-overs. I do try to speak a little louder at the start, but after a few minutes I tend to forget and from there it tends to go downwards. Maybe I should have some kind of reminder every minute or so. By the way, do you know if there are any video's I could watch explaining your techniques?

Answer (score 3):

To Sound less nasal you really need to work out how to speak less from your sinuses and more from your chest and throat.

That nasal sound comes from a lot of air coming from your nose, rather than your your mouth, so try opening your mouth more, lowering your tongue, possibly lowering the pitch as well.

Comment: I guess that is easier said than done. I have no idea where my sinuses are, nor how to speak from my chest or throat. Do you maybe know of some video's I can watch that illustrate some of these techniques?

Answer (score 1):

Have an ENT or otolaryngologist check your adenoids, too. If they're large or obtrusive, they can greatly affect airflow in the head.

Comment: I agree with Jim see what you can do medically to fix your sinuses.

Answer (score 0):

Pinch your nose as you sing and start to sing low and keep going higher. If your sound gets smaller then work on opening your mouth a little wider and lifting your soft palate.